# What's a good resource for learning about applying linear regression to practical problems?

Tags: regression

I think I'm mostly solid on the theory side of linear regression, but not so much on the practical side. I'm looking for a good resource on applying linear regression to practical problems, and how to handle common issues like heteroscedasticity, dependent errors (e.g., autocorrelation in times series data), violation of normality assumptions, nonlinearity, etc... and also tricks like applying transformations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I really like statistical rethinking. It is for bayesian regression, but super accessible a d gives a lot of good tricks and insights.

Comment: I would say it depends on in what field of knowledge you plan to apply regression analysis. Economics, psychology, sociology etc.

Comment: @JesperforPresident I'm going into the financial industry, so I'll probably be working on applying methods to stock market data.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you will get lots of opinions here since a good introductory text is a subjective ask. That said, you might want to look at something like Weisberg's *Applied Linear Regression*. That is used by a number of graduate statistics programs I know and covers all of those issues. It is a little light on autocorrelations; however, you would want a proper time series book for that -- something like Box, Jenkins, and Reinsel's *Time Series Analysis*.